# Ringing multiple phones or apps with Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-studio

I have a Twilio number

- I have a `TwiML app` (3rd party web app)
- I have a `SIP phone` (configured to a SIP domain)
- I have a `regular mobile phone`

I know Twilio is very powerful, but also complex. I try to find out how I can achieve one of the following scenarios:

1. All phones should ring simultanously
2. If one phone is picked up
3. Other phones should stop ringing

I am quite sure, that this could be done. But I do not know how?

It is not important, which Tools used (`Studio`, `Functions`, `TwiML`, `Google Code`, or a mix of these...)

First I thought I can do this completely in Studio. I know I can ring multiple PSTN phones together, but how can I solve that with different types of phones.

**Can someone please point mein the right direction?** Maybe there is some "tutorial" or example code, I did not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if Studio can handle making calls simultaneously to SIP and regular phones, but you can definitely achieve this with TwiML.

To ring more than one phone at a time, you use the [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) verb and nest the endpoints that you want to dial within. For dialling a regular phone you can use [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number) and for dialling a SIP phone you can use [`<Sip>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip).

```xml
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number>YOUR_MOBILE_PHONE_NUMBER</Number>
    <Sip>sip:username@exampl.com</Sip>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

The [documentation for parallel calling with Sip](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip?code-sample=code-parallel-calling&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=6.x#examples-6) does note that:

> In order to use the SIP Parallel Calling Twilio feature, you must enable the "Enhanced Programmable SIP Features" in your [Voice settings in the Console](https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/voice/settings/general?frameUrl=%2Fconsole%2Fvoice%2Fsettings%3Fx-target-region%3Dus1).

Comment: Hi @philnash, one more question left. How to redirect this to an 2Twiml App" too? I didn't found out how. So also the WebApp I use should ring. Do you have any suggestions? My current "REQUEST URL" is like this: `https://app.ofTheServiceiUse.com/twilio/iovoice?nid=6171940740923392&uid=4784637581721600&twimleturl=http%3A%2F%2Ftwimlets.com%2Fvoicemail%3FEmail%3Dmymail@something.com&timeout=30`. Is this done with the SID somehow? Or do I need a "Function"? Twilio is so confusing for me :-(

Comment: Hi Jan, I’m afraid that I’ve been laid off from Twilio, so I’m no longer in the position to help. This sounds like a bit of a different question though, so your best bet is to ask a new question with all the details and hopefully one of my remaining colleagues will be able to answer it.